# Why am i getting an error when creating a view

Tags: mysql

i know this is simple but im just having a brain fart. Mysql creating a vew from an export script

> ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longtext
>   ,`Community` longtext
>   ,`Lot` longtext
>   ,`Address` longtext
>   ,`City` longt' at line 2

**sql :**

```
CREATE VIEW `Builder_Findings_1_2` (
`Builder` longtext
,`Community` longtext
,`Lot` longtext
,`Address` longtext
,`City` longtext
,`State` longtext
,`Zip` longtext
,`Requested QA Date` longtext
,`Inspection Type` longtext
,`Area` longtext
,`Component` longtext
,`Item Description` longtext
,`Trade` longtext
,`Notes` longtext
,`ID` longtext
);
```

Comment: A view requires a query.  Perhaps you just want to create table?

Comment: `CREATE VIEW ...` should have `FROM` part

Comment: ^^ Also *should* have an `AS` as well as `FROM` as well as `SELECT` lol  --  A lot missing here ..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: that was from an export. that part was error out. Maybe i should just exclude that part from the import. Im exporting the views from a MySQL db to another. Everything else works fine except the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.

Thus, to create a view in MySQL, you have to use the following syntax :

```sql
CREATE VIEW Builder_Findings_1_2 AS
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```